# Why does React Native's serializable communication make it possible to use Chrome Dev Tools to debug?

Tags: react-native

I am learning React Native and would like to know why 
React Native's serializable communication makes it possible to use Chrome's debugger. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is phrased this way due to this sentence from React Native's homepage:

> The communication is also fully serializable, which allows us to leverage Chrome Developer Tools to debug the JavaScript while running the complete app, either in the simulator or on a physical device.

To understand that, you have to know a little bit more about how React Native works. The "communication" discussed here is the communication between your UI layer, and the JS processing layer. In React Native, this UI layer is the native elements of your iOS or Android app.

The conversations between the two are fully serializable, which means they're able to be converted into a stream of bytes (serialized), sent over the communication channel, and then regenerated (deserialized) on the other end.

The Chrome based React Native debugging tools proxy between the communication of the UI layer and the JS processing layer. It's possible to use the tools to do this because they can just play the same deserialization/serialization game the communication method can play but parse the contents of the message and show it to you first.

Comment: You can look through the iOS code for how the debugger works, to understand it better: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTWebSocketExecutor.m